# Issue with z-indexes within an iframe

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, internet-explorer-8, z-index

I am developing an asp.net web application that will be used within an iFrame in an existing application. The application needs to support IE8 and above.

The application looks fine alone in IE8, but once you render it within the iFrame it seems to disregard z-indexing. This is essentially the code I'm trying to use.

HTML:

```
<div id="top" class="block">
    <div id="clueTipOuter">
        <div class="show">
            Show ClueTip
        </div>
        <div class="clueTip">                                                            
            Some Text
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
<div id="bottom" class="block">
    content and cluetip
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    background-color:lightgrey;
    border:thin solid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position:relative;
}
.clueTip {
    display:none;
    background-color:white;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:20;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.clueTipOuter').each(function {
    var show = $(this).find('.show');
    var clueTip = $(this).find('.clueTip');    

    show.mouseover(function () {
        clueTip.css({ 'left': event.clientX + 20, 'top': event.clientY - 15});
        clueTip.show(150);
    });

    $(this).mouseleave(function () {
        clueTip.hide(80);
    }
});
```

Using IE8 with the iFrame, the "clueTip" ends up displaying underneath the "below" div. I'm lost as to why this could be happening.

I've scoured the forum and found plenty of post's about z-indexing, but none that really answer my question. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

I didn't think it was possible for an iframe to be causing these inconsistencies, turn's out it isn't... Our existing app displays in compatibility mode by default, which turned out to be the root cause of this issue in IE.

On the off chance someone else has this same exact issue, I figured I would provide what insight I've come up with.